# How to remove vertex from vertex group in edit mode with python?

Tags: python, scripting, vertex-groups

How to remove vertex from vertex group in edit mode with python?

I know I can use Bmesh to assign weight to vertex to vertex group in edit mode, but to remove it I have no idea.

Or do I really have to make the scene go object mode and come back to edit mode?

Comment: You don't have to, see: [Remove all selected vertices from all Vertex-Groups](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126887/31447)

Comment: I want to specify which vertex group and what vertex to remove, this only work on active vertex group if im not wrong

Comment: That's one of those tiny details you should add to your question...